# Choosing a long-term storage/analytic system?

Tags: azure, storage, bigdata, analytics, azure-hdinsight

A brief summary of the project I'm working on:

I was hired as a web dev intern at a small company (part of a larger corporation) close to the state college I attend. For the past couple months, myself and two other interns have been working on the front-end as well as the back-end. The company is prototyping adding sensors to its products (oil/gas industry); we were tasked with building the portal that customers could login to to see data from their machines even if they're not near them.

Basically, we're collecting sensor data (~ten sensors/machine) and it's sent back to us. Where we're stuck is determining the best way to store and analyze long term data. We have a Redis Cache set up for fast access by the front-end, where only the lastest set of data for each machine is stored. But for historical data, I (and my coworkers) are having a tough time deciding the best route to go. Our whole project is based in VS (C#/Razor) with Azure integration (which is amazing by the way), so I'd like to keep the long term storage there as well. As far as I can tell, HDinsight + data in a BLOB seems to be the best option, but I'm fairly green when it comes to backend solutions. I would just like input from some older developers who may have more experience in this area, as we are the only developers here besides a couple older members who are more involved in the engineering side of things vs. development.

So, professionals of stack overflow, what would be your recommendation for long-term data storage and analytics?

PS: I apologize if I have HDinsight confused. From what I understand, it maps data in BLOB storage into HBase for easier analytics? Hadoop/HBase confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation would be Azure Table storage. It provides a highly scalable and low cost data archival solution. If designed properly, you can also get a very decent query performance. Refer to the [Azure Storage Table Design Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) for more details.

My second choice would be [Azure DocumentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-introduction/) service which is a NoSQL document database. It costs a bit more but querying data is much more flexible.

You should only go with [HDInsight](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/hdinsight/) when you have a specific need as it's a resource-intensive and expensive service. Once you identify a specific requirement for a big-data analysis that's when you import your data and process it with HDInsight.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. In reply to that last paragraph, we're attempting to determine trends from the data in regards to machine failure, so at some point down the road we can warn customers when their machines are at risk of (statistically) failing. That's why I was considering HDInsight. Is it possible to implement HDInsight down the road if we setup table storage or documentDB now? Or would that require moving our data to a new file system?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to import data from DocumentDB to HDInsight using the DocumentDB's Hadoop connector: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-run-hadoop-with-hdinsight/

Comment: You may also want to take a look at Azure Machine Learning for predictive  analytics: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-what-is-machine-learning/. It can easily access data from Azure Table storage.

Comment: So if I went the Table Storage route (seems simple enough), I could use AML to analyze the data later? I've found tutorials for using Table Storage and HDInsight together, or should I either go Table Storage/Machine Learning or DocDB/HDInsight? Basically it seems like there's a ton of options and I'm just having a hard time nailing down the "right" combination.

Comment: I'd focus on the storage solution requirements first - evaluate Table storage vs. DocumentDB to see what works best for your application. I'm sure there are ways to get your data into Azure ML and HDInsight from both Table storage and DocumentDB.